# Can I prevent Chrome from storing passwords in Keychain, instead just save it to itself?

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, password, keychain

Can I set up Chrome to not store passwords in the Keychain?

I'd like to be able to use Chrome as *my* browser on her Macbook, without having my passwords shared into Safari and Firefox (which she uses).  That's how we've shared this computer for a long time (which means I don't have to bother logging out fully and logging in as my own account), and since upgrading to Yosemite it has changed behavior here.

Answer (score 1):

Open Chrome then on the right site click on

Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.
Select Settings.
Click Show advanced settings.
Under the "Passwords and forms" section check the "Offer to save your web passwords" checkbox **if you want Google Chrome to prompt you to save** your password every time you sign in to a new website.

Open your KeyChain and find the Google/Chrome passwords that you do not want to share. Open and select Access control. Now use one of the available options to your desire (to share or not).

Comment: is there a way to get chrome to save my passwords to itself rather than to keychain?

Comment: Is that another question? yes it is possible to do that as well.

Comment: this is what I was really trying to ask, so same question but clariified